# Buffer to buffer compress using bzlib in C++

Tags: c++

After many years I have decided to use C++ again as progamming language and unfortunately at the moment I am quite rusty at it. I'm implementing a function to compress text using BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong in my code as I get an access violation error in the last line. Is there a good soul that can help me? Thanks a lot.
The code is as follows

```
unsigned int data_len = strlen(data) + 1;
// Suggested buffer
unsigned int dest_len = data_len * 1.01 + 600; 
char *dest = (char*)malloc(dest_len);
// Suggested values
int blockSize100k = 9;
int verbosity = 0;
int workFactor = 30;
BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress(dest, &dest_len, data, data_len, blockSize100k, verbosity, workFactor);
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide some links to the documentation for the random function you are calling that is failing. For all we know `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress` is defined to "always result in an access violation", and so is behaving exactly to specification!

Comment: Is data actually a c style string or buffer?

Comment: Thank you for answering.I just based my code according to this documentation
http://www.bzip.org/1.0.5/bzip2-manual-1.0.5.html#bzbufftobuffcompress
but probably I might have missed something. I'm going to read it again now.

Comment: Just to put an EOF to my question, some updates.
I have decided to move from BZlib to Zlib (http://www.zlib.net/) for I could find better documentation and examples to be used for my needs.
As I said above, I've gone back to C++ after many years and for my current level of knowledge it is not easy to improve without good code examples.
This is basically an invitation to release code accompanied by clear examples, not only for insiders, better some simple lines of code than 1000 words.
Thank you.
Good bytes.